# proving a inequality with fibonacci's sequence using strong induction (given excercise.10)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Exercise: Use $I_2$ to prove that $\alpha^{n-2}\le f_n\le \alpha^{n-1}$ for every positive integer $n$. Note that it is again necessary to make the first part of the proof for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

$I_2$ here means that we have to use strong induction. The variable $\alpha =\frac {1+\sqrt 5} {2}$

---

Attempt: I showed it holds for $n=1,2$ already and then assumed it held for up to $k$.

Im struggling on how to show it holds for $k+1$. I attempted to solve the left inequality first using the definition of fibonacci sequence $F_{k+1}= F_{k-1} + F_k$ and then using the induction hypothesis.

$F_k= F_{k-1}+F_{k}$

$x^{k-3}\le F_{k-1}\le x^{k-2}$
and
$x^{k-2}\le F_k\le x^{k-1}$  (by our inductive hypothesis) (I replaced $x$ with $\alpha$)

therefore,

$$F_{k-1}\ge x^{k-3} + x^{k-2}\\ \ge x^{k-2}(x^{-1}+1)\\ \ge x^{k-2}(x^{-2})\\ \ge x^{k-4}$$

This is obviously wrong not sure why though!

$F_{k+1}\ge x^{k-4}$   (I replaced $\alpha$ with $x$). obviously not what I wanted which is $x^{k-1}\le F_{k+1}$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140410/discussion-on-question-by-cheesewiz-proving-a-inequality-with-fibonaccis-sequen).

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use strong induction. After having checked for the case of $n=1$ and $n=2$, you should say:

Let $m>2$ be a natural number such that for all natural numbers $m'<m$, the statement in question is true.

This ensures that the statement is true for $m-1$ and $m-2$. I am assuming here they want you to use the recurrence relation $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$.

As it is currently written, you induction hypothesis does not imply the inequalities you say it does.

These are the flaws so far. I am not too sure on how to prove it yet.

Comment: FYI, regarding how to prove the statement, please see either of the $2$ duplicates I found & stated in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568568/proving-a-inequality-with-fibonaccis-sequence-using-strong-induction-given-exc#comment9613358_4568568).

Comment: The moved to chat comment was: Does this answer your question? [Proving that $\alpha^{n-2}\leq F_n\leq \alpha^{n-1}$ for all $n\geq 1$, where $\alpha$ is the golden ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269538) - found using [an Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Calpha%5E%7Bn-2%7D%5Cle%20f_n%5Cle%5Calpha%5E%7Bn-1%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Calpha%3D%5Cfrac%20%7B1%2B%5Csqrt%205%7D%7B2%7D%24&p=1). Another duplicate is [Fibonacci : demonstration by induction : $\phi^{n-2} \leq F_n \leq \phi^{n-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3878044)

Comment: @JohnOmielan your link to the other duplicate was wrong (still visible in the chat) but I repaired it here.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for doing that handling. FYI, the reason the link was wrong is that, to keep the lengths to a minimum, I usually use relative paths for the links. Unfortunately, when the comment is moved to chat, that link is now referencing the chat site instead, so it's incorrect.